# Flycheck Autocorrect errors

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, flycheck

Hello Community I am using Spacemacs and I love it. It is working great for me all his features and the way all the layers are organized is amazing. Right now I am working with typescript but this question is common for any language.

I correctly setup flycheck and it is working perfectly. It is signaling all the errors.

How I can make Flycheck correct all the syntax errors in a bulk for me? Right now I am going one by one adding a semicolon or a space or who knows; it should be a function or something that allow me run an script that correct all this errors.